# POST huge JSON object in Android

Tags: android, http-post, out-of-memory, json

I would like to post a huge JSON object, but when i try i got this error:

```
0 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
1 at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:432)
2 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:642)
3 at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:723)
4 at java.io.StringWriter.toString(StringWriter.java:100)
5 at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:528)
6 at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:507)
7 at dk.companyoung.jobpatrulje.SendDialog$1.onClick(SendDialog.java:87)
```

Here is my code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://blabla.dk");

//Making post-objekt
post p = new post();
p.companies = arr;
p.name = activist.getText().toString();
p.phone = cpr.getText().toString();
p.password = "hey";
p.receipt = receipt.getText().toString();


Gson gson = new Gson();

//Its fails here.               
String jsonEn = gson.toJson(p);
httppost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(jsonEn.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));

HttpResponse status = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Can someone possibly tell me what's wrong and maybe give me an example :) 
It would be great! Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid this error when you work with huge JSON objects you need to use streaming JSON parsers - http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Streaming_API_Example. There are two of them suitable for Android: `GSON` and `Jackson`.

My favorite one is [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

It is really simple and very fast. But of course you can try to use `GSON`: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

By the way in `GSON` docs you can find explanation of your problem:

```
 Most applications should use only the object model API. 
 JSON streaming is useful in just a few situations:
 When it is impossible or undesirable to load the entire 
 object model into memory. This is most relevant on mobile 
 platforms where memory is limited.
```

In one of my paid Android application I used `Jackson` with huge `JSON` objects in `POST` context but for POST queries I used `Spring RestTemplate` library. : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html . I don't know if it will be useful for you. Here is my code for serializing huge `LinkedHashMap` to JSON with `Jackson` library and posting it to remote server:

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, Object>  executeServerCommand
                                (String commandToExecute, LinkedHashMap<String, Object> parameters) 
      {             
 LinkedHashMap<String, Object> resultofOperation =
                             new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    ObjectMapper mapParametersToFromJackson = new ObjectMapper();
    StringWriter stringRepresentation = new StringWriter();
    try {
      mapParametersToFromJackson.writeValue(stringRepresentation, parameters);
    } 
    catch (JsonGenerationException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (JsonMappingException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    String postData = "params=" + stringRepresentation.toString();
    requestHeaders.setContentLength(postData.length());
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity =
              new HttpEntity<String>(postData,requestHeaders);
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory preconfiguredHTTPInstance =
                               new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    RestTemplate restfulRequest = new RestTemplate(preconfiguredHTTPInstance);
    restfulRequest.setRequestFactory(preconfiguredHTTPInstance);
    restfulRequest.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    ResponseEntity<String> responseFromServer = restfulRequest.postForEntity(NetworkCommands.MAIN_URL + commandToExecute,
    requestEntity, String.class);
    String serverResponseBody = responseFromServer.getBody();
```

Comment: Hey Alexander ! Thanks for your answer! 
Do you have an example of how to use it in a post-context?

Comment: @ThomasBolander Hi.You can see my edits.May be it will help you